# AspxGridView selection at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net, aspxgridview

I have an `aspxGridView` on my page, and i create the columns at runtime. I also add `CommandColumn` with `ShowSelectCheckBox` set to true. But after i select one row and click a button to get the row values, `AspxGridView.Selection.Count` returns `0`. I create this `GridView` on AspxButtons Click event also for paging, create the gridView on `Page_Init`. Here is the code to create the `AspxGridView`:

```
Colenter code hereorCollection colorCol = ConfAttributesManager.Instance
                                                               .GetColors();

if (colorCol.Count > 0)
{
    GridViewDataTextColumn grdColorCodeColumn = new GridViewDataTextColumn();
    grdColorCodeColumn.FieldName = "ColorCode";

    GridViewDataTextColumn grdDescriptionColumn = new GridViewDataTextColumn();
    grdDescriptionColumn.FieldName = "Description";

    gv_Attributes.Columns.Clear();
    gv_Attributes.Columns.Add(grdColorCodeColumn);
    gv_Attributes.Columns.Add(grdDescriptionColumn);
    GridViewCommandColumn grdCmdColumn = new GridViewCommandColumn();
    grdCmdColumn.ShowSelectCheckbox = true;
    grdCmdColumn.VisibleIndex = 0;
    gv_Attributes.Columns.Add(grdCmdColumn);

    gv_Attributes.DataSource = colorCol;
    gv_Attributes.DataBind();
 }
```

I don't know where do i make a mistake?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: When you create the columns at runtime are you doing it every time or is it in a if(!Page.IsPostback) { } block?

Comment: If your task is just to select the current row and do some operation on top of that, then why don';t use RowCommand event and check if commandname = 'select' and then get the current row (something like http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @Mark i also create the columns at page_init. @Subhlash Dike, i can't use that event because user first selects the row he wanted and then click a button. So that event, in my scenerio, is not useful.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you do not specify the ASPxGridView.KeyFieldName property that is required for Row Selection operation:

```
gv_Attributes.KeyFieldName = "ColorCode";
//gv_Attributes.KeyFieldName = Unique Key Field;
```